# Regexp search result hightlight with accent

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, search, highlight

Can someone help me to improve my search please ? I try to highlight several words when a user write one or many things in the input. I am using this function :

```
checkHighlightList(originalStr, queries) {
    const regexp = new RegExp(queries.join('|'), 'gi');
    const matchs = originalStr.match(regexp);
    if (matchs) {
      const result = originalStr.replace(regexp, match => `<span class="highlight">${ match }</span>`);
      return result;
    }
  }
```

The problem is, if I have the word "pokémon" in my queries and I write "kemon". It doesn't work because every accent characters are different (ô !== o). I would like to write "ke" or "ké" in my input and highlight the "ké" part in "pokémon". I use some french words who contains a lot of accent on it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search accented text without accent in the search terms you can define an accent map, and compose a regex from that:

```js
accentMap = {
  ae: '(ae|æ|ǽ|ǣ)',
  a:  '(a|á|ă|ắ|ặ|ằ|ẳ|ẵ|ǎ|â|ấ|ậ|ầ|ẩ|ẫ|ä|ǟ|ȧ|ǡ|ạ|ȁ|à|ả|ȃ|ā|ą|ᶏ|ẚ|å|ǻ|ḁ|ⱥ|ã)',
  c:  '(c|ć|č|ç|ḉ|ĉ|ɕ|ċ|ƈ|ȼ)',
  e:  '(e|é|ĕ|ě|ȩ|ḝ|ê|ế|ệ|ề|ể|ễ|ḙ|ë|ė|ẹ|ȅ|è|ẻ|ȇ|ē|ḗ|ḕ|ⱸ|ę|ᶒ|ɇ|ẽ|ḛ)',
  i:  '(i|í|ĭ|ǐ|î|ï|ḯ|ị|ȉ|ì|ỉ|ȋ|ī|į|ᶖ|ɨ|ĩ|ḭ)',
  n:  '(n|ń|ň|ņ|ṋ|ȵ|ṅ|ṇ|ǹ|ɲ|ṉ|ƞ|ᵰ|ᶇ|ɳ|ñ)',
  o:  '(o|ó|ŏ|ǒ|ô|ố|ộ|ồ|ổ|ỗ|ö|ȫ|ȯ|ȱ|ọ|ő|ȍ|ò|ỏ|ơ|ớ|ợ|ờ|ở|ỡ|ȏ|ō|ṓ|ṑ|ǫ|ǭ|ø|ǿ|õ|ṍ|ṏ|ȭ)',
  u:  '(u|ú|ŭ|ǔ|û|ṷ|ü|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ|ǖ|ṳ|ụ|ű|ȕ|ù|ủ|ư|ứ|ự|ừ|ử|ữ|ȗ|ū|ṻ|ų|ᶙ|ů|ũ|ṹ|ṵ)'
};

function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

function checkHighlightList(str, queries) {
  accentRegex = new RegExp(Object.keys(accentMap).join('|'), 'g');
  const queryRegex = new RegExp(queries.map(q => {
    return escapeRegExp(q).toLowerCase().replace(accentRegex, m => {
      return accentMap[m] || m;
    });
  }).join('|'), 'gi');
  return str.replace(queryRegex, m => `<span class="highlight">${ m }</span>`);
}

let source = 'Pokémon & Crème Brulée';
let result = checkHighlightList(source, [ 'kemon', 'creme' ]);
console.log('source:\n  "' + source + '"');
console.log('result:\n  "' + result + '"');
```

Output for search terms `[ 'kemon', 'creme' ]`:

```
source:
  "Pokémon & Crème Brulée"
result:
  "Po<span class="highlight">kémon</span> & <span class="highlight">Crème</span> Brulée"
```

Explanation of `accentRegex`:

- it is an OR regex of all keys of `accentMap`:

  - example: `/ae|a|c|e|i|n|o|u/g`
  - tweak the map as needed for additional accent chars

Explanation of `queryRegex`:

- it is an OR regex of all query terms, where each key in accentMap gets mapped to an OR regex of all accented version of that key

  - example: query term `cafe` results in this (shortened) regex: `/c(a|á|ă|ắ|ặ|ǎ|â|ậ|ä|ȧ|à|)f(e|é|ĕ|ě|ệ|ë|ė|è|ẽ)/gi`

**Note:** Since the query terms are user specified and used in a regex, we need to escape the regex symbols in the user input, hence the use of function `escapeRegExp()`.

Comment: Note that the queries parameter builds a regex and not a substring. `checkHighlightList(str, ['P.k'])` will highlight "Pok"

Comment: @Vitim.us: Indeed, the query terms need to be escaped due to use in regex, I'll update the post (later)

Comment: I updted the code with a `escapeRegExp()` function.

Comment: Yes thank you for the explanation part. it's really helpful to understand how it works.

Comment: Yes, your answer is now validated ! Have a good week !

Comment: A quick update, don't forget to add toString() before replace. It could return an error if the queries is not a string. And an other cool update should be to allow the user to write "poké" and the searching highlight "poke" (accent match to no accent word)

Comment: For the latter case you can create a reverse accent map

Comment: Or, with recent browsers (ES2015/ES6) you can do this: `str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")`